# Laurent series of this function

Tags: taylor-expansion, complex-integration, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series of the function$$
f(z) = \frac{z+1}{z(z-4)}
$$
in the annulus $0<|z-4|<4$.

My approach:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(z) &= \frac{z+1}{z(z-4)} =\left(\frac{-1}{4}\frac{1}{z}+\frac{5}{4}\frac{1}{z-4}\right)\\
&=\frac{-1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{5}{4-z}\right) = \frac{-1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{5}{4}\frac{1}{1-z/4}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
By the region, I'm pretty sure the second term in the expression would just be $\sum(\frac{z}{4})^n$. I am not sure how to deal with $1/z$ in the bracket cause it seems we cannot determine whether $z$ is in the region or not. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Hint: Expand $(z-4)f(z)$ into a power series about $4$.

Comment: $f(z) = \frac{z+1}{z(z-4)}=\frac{-1}{4z}+\frac{5}{4(z-4)}$ and now $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{z-4+4}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\frac{z-4}4+1}$ and as$\frac{ |z-4|}{4}<1$ so we can write $\frac{1}{\frac{z-4}4+1}= \frac{1}{1-(-1)(\frac{z-4}4)}=  \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \left(\frac{z-4}4\right)^{n}
 $

Answer (score 3):

The region is centered at $z=4$, so the series should be as well. The series in the question is centered at $z=0$.

Partial fractions is a good way to go, but the $(z+1)$ can, and should, be included in the partial fractions.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{z+1}{z(z-4)}
&=\frac14\left(\frac5{z-4}-\frac1z\right)\tag1\\[3pt]
&=\frac14\left(\frac5{z-4}-\frac1{4+(z-4)}\right)\tag2\\
&=\frac14\left(\frac5{z-4}-\frac{1/4}{1+\frac{z-4}4}\right)\tag3\\
&=\frac{5/4}{z-4}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^{k+2}(z-4)^k\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: partial fractions
$(2)$: center the second term at $z=4$
$(3)$: write the second term as $\frac1{1+x}$
$(4)$: apply the series for $\frac1{1+x}$

Comment: so for Laurent series, we do not need to worry about the terms at the center even when the norm is over 1? basically I'm trying to clarify that we can leave the $\frac{1}{x-a}$ alone when the center is at $a$?

Comment: The function blows up near $z=4$, so we are going to get a part of the expansion that blows up as well. $\frac{5/4}{z-4}$ is that part. The comment about the norm being over $1$ leads me to believe that you are worried about series convergence. The only convergence we have to worry about is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^{k+2}(z-4)^k$ and that converges as long as $|z-4|\lt4$.

Comment: i see. thanks a lot!